# How do I right click with a Magic Trackpad?

Tags: 11.04, unity, multi-touch, magic-trackpad

I can't seem to right click with my Magic Trackpad on Ubuntu 11.04. On maverick, a two-finger tap would do, but in natty it seems to be assigned to *middle* click, and three-finger tap is assigned to dragging a window.

My Magic Trackpad is basically unusable because of this, with many programs requiring right click and very few even using the middle click (still, I'd like to have both. maybe have three-finger tap as middle click and four-finger drag window?)

Answer (score 1):

Right Click with Two Fingers does work with the Magic trackpad by default in Ubuntu 11.04. Under Mouse Preferences in the Control Panel you will also find a "Touchpad" tab with more configuration options.

Try removing all trackpad entries from your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. Some  settings that were needed for earlier versions of ubuntu are not needed to get the Magic Trackpad to work and some legacy settings cause unexpected problems like yours - left and right click not working as expected.

Comment: **Didn't** work, still middle clicks :S